# Customize Keybord key combination

Tags: visual-studio-2010, laptop

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad Edge laptop.
when I am trying to debug in  Visual studio, I need to press the Fn + F6 keys combination.

I don't want to do it like that. 
Can anyone help me to customize the key combination by just F6 for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a setting in your laptop BIOS to reverse Fn key? Visual Studio is not aware of Fn key at all.

Simply go to your BIOS settings and look for such a setting. Disable it.