# Microsoft Sculpt mobile keyboard reverse Fn keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have just got my new Microsoft sculpt mobile keyboard, and it works fine.

However the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are reversed by design.

I mean by pressing F6 for example, the Search charm appears on Windows 8, and i can use <kbd>F6</kbd> if i press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key together with it. Is there any way i can change how it works? It would be verry important for me, i lost many hotkey combination this way :\
Its a bluetooth wireless keyboard, i could not finy any bios setting for it (like some laptops, but i'm on desktop PC). i have

Comment: Yes, some laptops do have a setting for Fn key reversal (for example [1](http://superuser.com/questions/279809/hp-laptop-f1-12-keys-inverted-with-fn), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/360892/customize-keybord-key-combination), [3](http://superuser.com/questions/561365/disabling-function-keys-in-windows-8-with-autohotkey)), but in your case of course you'll have to check whether the keyboard's driver or software provides this option. If not an AutoHotkey script might be the only solution.

Comment: It has no provided software where i can change settings- If i have to use AutoHotkey, i will simply not use the keyboard itself :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per @AkA Kin and @Yuji it seems that AutoHotKey is the solution. Found this great script by tehshane that "remaps the F1-F12 function keys on the Microsoft Sculpt Mobile keyboard to be pressed without having to use the Fn key":
https://gist.github.com/tehshane/8765405

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I do not intend to use third-party software for a keyboard to work fine. I did not try your solution but I accept your answer as a solution, since you said it works for all function keys. Does it make the function keys work by default, or does it completely wipe away the secondary functions (like volume settings)?

Answer (score 8):

The hardwiring of the Windows 8 Keys as the default keys instead of the more often used Function Keys drove me nuts.  I have far more use for the F1 to F12 keys than the Windows 8 Keys, particularly in Mac OS X.

This is a hardwired feature of the Microsoft Sculpt Mobile Keyboard.

The only solution which works is to sacrifice the Windows 8 keys by **permanently setting the Fn in the down position.**

**I did this by popping off the Fn Key and taping the switch in the down position.  I used double-stick permanent mounting tape for adhesion which was then covered by black gaffers tape.**

I love that my Function Keys now work as I want them to.

Sure, I no longer have keyboard support for volume - compared to the Microsoft Bluetooth Mobile Keyboard 6000.  But I do gain a hardwired Home and End Keys.  And I can easily create a macro to control the volume.

Since the Sculpt Keyboard is also half the price of the Keyboard 6000, this hardware modification saves me $20 every time I wear out the keyboard.

I wouldn't worry about battery life from keeping the Fn key pressed down since usually I turn off the keyboard when not used - when the keyboard is used as a mobile keyboard.  When used as a desktop keyboard, we will have to see if battery life is reduced.

Comment: just a note on the hardware mod: once that key pops off you will never get it back on! There are 2 fragile, interlocking nylon levers which form a challenging puzzle to put back together. They are now in the bin, and I have a big blob of blu-tack holding the key down.

Answer (score 2):

There's no solution... yet. See this thread:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bdb36756-b0d3-49f7-932a-ca9d6108192a/sculpt-mobile-keyboard-is-not-recognized-by-mouse-and-keyboard-center

Answer (score 2):

I installed AutoHotKey and the following script worked for me. I'm using Windows 7 though... Don't know if that matters.

```
Media_Play_Pause::F1
Volume_Mute::F2
return
Volume_Down::F3
Volume_Up::F4
<+<#F21::F5
<!<#F21::
Send,{F6}
return
<^<#F21::
Send,{F7}
return
<#F21::
Send,{Blind}{F8}
return
<^<#BS::
Send,{F9}
return
<^<#Tab::
Send,{F10}
return
<!<#F22::
Send,{F11}
return
<^<#F23::
Send,{F12}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a keyboard shortcut for this on the keyboard covers for the Surface (which is also locked in "media key" mode by default): **Fn+CapsLock**.  It's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

After A long time search 
I find Autohotkey can resolve <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>, but for <kbd>F5</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> It's not very easy to use.
I don't want to wast my time to learn how to use that.
The easiest way is past a Scotch tape on the <kbd>FN</kbd> key I think....